# Invalid column name importing from XML to SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, sqlxml

I'm getting an error trying to import a XML file to SQL. The code looks like this:

```
USE MyDB

declare @xmldata as xml

set @xmldata = (SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn)AS Bulkcolumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'FILENAME', SINGLE_BLOB) as X)

INSERT INTO BenCalCopy1(BenefitCalcID, RangeBenID, CalculationID)
SELECT 

BenefitCalcID AS [BenefitCalcID],
RangeBenID AS [RangeBenID],
CalculationID AS [CalculationID]
```

The error message given is:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'BenefitCalcID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'RangeBenID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Invalid column name 'CalculationID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid column name 'BenefitCalcID'.
```

And the XML File is given as:

```
<row>
  <BenefitCalcID>'intvalue'</BenefitCalcID>
  <RangeBenID>'intvalue'</RangeBenID>
  <CalculationID>'intvalue'</CalculationID>
</row>
```

Comment: and select from xml statement looks like?..

Comment: not sure how to call the select from in terms of an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

As you indicated that the values are INT, I have 'INT' in the parsed xml columns.  However, if the values are not INT you can change it to 'VARCHAR(MAX)' or whatever you need.  Also keep in mind that the xml nodes (path) are case sensitive.  For example '/row' does not equal '/Row'.  So if you need to update the node path keep that in mind.  Hope this works for you.

```
DECLARE @XMLTable AS TABLE
(
    XMLData XML
)


DECLARE @XMLData AS XML

set @xmldata = (SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn)AS Bulkcolumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'FILENAME', SINGLE_BLOB) as X)


INSERT INTO @XMLTable
SELECT @XMLData

--SELECT * FROM @XMLTable

INSERT INTO BenCalCopy1(BenefitCalcID, RangeBenID, CalculationID)
SELECT 
     Data.value('(./BenefitCalcID)[1]','INT') BenefitCalcID
    ,Data.value('(./RangeBenID)[1]','INT') RangeBenID
    ,Data.value('(./CalculationID)[1]','INT') CalculationID
FROM
    @XMLTable X
    CROSS APPLY X.XMLData.nodes('/row') AS Tbl(Data)
```

**Edit for SQL Server 2005:**

```
CREATE TABLE #XMLTable
(
    XMLData XML
)


DECLARE @XMLData AS XML

set @xmldata = (SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn)AS Bulkcolumn FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'FILENAME', SINGLE_BLOB) as X)


INSERT INTO #XMLTable
SELECT @XMLData

--SELECT * FROM @XMLTable

INSERT INTO BenCalCopy1(BenefitCalcID, RangeBenID, CalculationID)
SELECT 
     Data.value('(./BenefitCalcID)[1]','INT') BenefitCalcID
    ,Data.value('(./RangeBenID)[1]','INT') RangeBenID
    ,Data.value('(./CalculationID)[1]','INT') CalculationID
FROM
    #XMLTable X
    CROSS APPLY X.XMLData.nodes('/row') AS Tbl(Data)
```

Comment: Msg 2370, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
XQuery [@XMLTable.XMLData.value()]: No more tokens expected at the end of the XQuery expression. Found ')'.

Comment: @DonaldDang I read up on it.  It is a SQL Server 2005 limitation using variable tables.  I edited the code to run as a temp table.

Comment: It is complaining now that BenefitCalcID is an invalid column name, specifically at line 19.

Comment: Does the SQL statement run fine when you are not doing the insert, just doing the select?

Comment: Alright, it gave me a new XML file but it didn't necessarily import it to the SQL table BenCalCopy1

Comment: Does xml parse correctly in the cross apply query if you comment out the insert?  If so you may want to check the spelling of the BenefitCalcID field in the insert statement.

Comment: Alright, it managed to import it to the table however BenefitCalcID is NULLed throughout, meaning the RangeBenID and CalculationID were imported but BenefitCalcID didn't. Strange.

Comment: What is the datatype of BenefitCalcID in the BenCalCopy1 table.  Can you also provide an actual value in the xml for the same field?  <BenefitCalcID>ActualValue</BenefitCalcID>  Is BenefitCalcID auto insert or a primary key in the BenCalCopy1 table?

Comment: it is an integer value.

Comment: I don't know.  It sounds like an issue with either the spelling of the BenefitCalcID or a datatype mismatch or a constraint for that field.  But I am unsure as it seems the XML is parsing correctly. Sorry.  Could not help more.